# Caesar Cipher -- "Isn't numeric in addition (+)"

Tags: perl, arguments

I'm creating a Caesar cipher using Perl, but I cant seem to find the error in the code.

I keep getting the error message:

> Argument "hello" isn't numeric in addition (+) at ./Lab03.pl line 66, <> line 1.

which is the line `$translated += $symbol`.

```
use warnings;
$x = 26;

sub getMode {

    $e = "encrypt decrypt";

    while ( 'True' ) {

        print "Do you wish to encrypt or decrypt a message? \n";
        $mode = <STDIN>;
        chomp( $mode );

        if ( $mode = split( //, $e ) ) {
            return $mode;
        }
        else {
            print "Enter either 'encrypt' or 'decrypt'.\n";
        }
    }
}

sub getMessage {

    print "Enter your message:";
    $input = <STDIN>;
    chomp( $input );

    return $input;
}

sub getKey {

    $key = 0;

    while ( 'True' ) {

        print "Enter the key number (1-26): ";
        $key = int( <> );
        chomp( $key );

        if ( $key >= 1 and $key <= $x ) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
}

sub getTranslatedMessage {
    ( $mode, $message, $key ) = @_;

    if ( $mode =~ /^d/ ) {
        $key        = -$key;
        $translated = '';
    }

    foreach $symbol ( $message ) {

        if ( $symbol =~ /[A-Za-z]/ ) {
            $num = ord( $symbol );
            $num += $key;
        }

        if ( $symbol =~ /^[A-Z]/ ) {

            if ( $num > ord( 'Z' ) ) {
                $num -= 26;
            }
            elsif ( $num < ord( 'A' ) ) {
                $num += 26;
            }
            elsif ( $symbol = /^[a-z]/ ) {

                if ( $num > ord( 'z' ) ) {
                    $num -= 26;
                }
                elsif ( $num < ord( 'a' ) ) {
                    $num += 26;
                }

                $translated += chr( $num );
            }
        }
        else {
            $translated += $symbol;
        }
    }

    return $translated;
}

$mode    = getMode();
$message = getMessage();
$key     = getKey();

print "Your translated text is: '\n' ";
print( getTranslatedMessage( $mode, $message, $key ) );
```

Comment: One of the first lessons you should learn is to add plenty of white space, especially indenting that follows the program's block structure. I've done it for you in this case. You must also *always* add `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` to the top of every Perl program you write, without exception. You will then need to *declare* each of your variables using `my` as close as possible to their first point of use. You have written far too much code before testing. It's best to write only a few lines of code at a time before you test to ensure that you have a solid base to proceed

Answer (score 2):

In Perl, `+` is numeric addition only.  String concatenation is `.` / `.=`.

Also:

```
if ($mode = split(//,$e)){
```

is incorrect.  I believe you want something like:

```
my %valid_mode = ( 'encrypt' => 1, 'decrypt' => 1);
...
    if ( $valid_mode{$mode} ) {
        return $mode
```

The code you have is setting $mode into the number of characters in $e (in an inefficient way).

Here:

```
foreach $symbol ($message){
```

in Perl, strings are first class entities; they aren't automatically interpreted as arrays of characters.  So to loop over the characters, you need to so something else.  The simplest way is:

```
foreach $symbol ( split //, $message ) {
```

Here:

```
    elsif ($symbol= /^[a-z]/){
```

`=` should be `=~`.

There is also a problem with which code is in which blocks that prevents upper case characters from being added to the output.  It looks to me like the closing brace for your fir st `if ($symbol =~` should be just before the later else, and other braces possibly fixed up to match.

Putting all your `}`'s on a line of their own, indented the same as the line with the corresponding `{` is a much better idea.  It will help you see mismatched braces much more easily.

Here is corrected code, with `use strict` added and all variables declared:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $x = 26;
sub getMode{
    my %valid_mode = ( 'encrypt' => 1, 'decrypt' => 1 );
    while ('True'){
        print"Do you wish to encrypt or decrypt a message? \n";
        my $mode = <STDIN>;
        chomp ( $mode);
        if ($valid_mode{$mode}) {
            return $mode;
        }
        else {
           print "Enter either 'encrypt' or 'decrypt'.\n";
        }
    }
}
sub getMessage{
    print"Enter your message:";
    my $input = <STDIN>;
    chomp ($input);
    return $input;
}

sub getKey{
    my $key = 0;
    while ('True'){
        print"Enter the key number (1-26): ";
        $key = int(<>);
        chomp ($key);
        if ($key >= 1 and $key <= $x){
            return $key;
        }
    }
}
sub getTranslatedMessage{
    my ($mode, $message, $key) = @_;
    if ($mode =~ /^d/){
        $key = -$key;
    }
    my $translated = '';

    foreach my $symbol (split //, $message){
        if ($symbol =~ /[A-Za-z]/){
            my $num = ord($symbol);
            $num += $key;

            if ($symbol =~ /^[A-Z]/){
                if ($num > ord('Z')){
                   $num -= 26;
                }
                elsif ($num < ord('A')){
                    $num += 26;
                }
            }
            elsif ($symbol=~ /^[a-z]/){
                if ($num > ord('z')){
                    $num -= 26;
                }
                elsif ($num < ord('a')){
                    $num += 26;
                }
            }

            $translated .= chr($num);
        }
        else{
            $translated .= $symbol;
        }
    }

    return $translated;
}

my $mode = getMode();
my $message = getMessage();
my $key = getKey();

print"Your translated text is:\n";
print(getTranslatedMessage($mode, $message, $key));
print "\n";
```

Over all, I suggest you write smaller chunks of code and test them to make sure they worked before assembling them all together.